# How can I use an ARM chip to read & write 4164 DRAM?

Tags: arm, cortex-m, dram

I have an idea I'd like to pursue and partly because of their speed and partly because I'd like to begin ARM development I think a Cortex based board might be a good fit. I'm quite a proficient programmer (30 years experience) but my electrical knowledge is just a bit beyond basic but improving. I have done quite a bit of Arduino projects previously.

My question is what would be the best way to read/write to 8-bit 200ns RAM? The RAM in question is dynamic and is refreshed by another system so this would purely be 16-bit addressing with an 8-bit data bus. There are some bus contention signals to take into account (video chip access gets priority). I was thinking that FSMC might do it (by reading answers to SRAM addressing questions) if I assume it were possible to introduce enough wait states but I'm finding it hard to locate the documentation on this.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be helpful to get me started. I am fully aware that I might be asking the impossible but I'm sure there must be a way.

Edit: As I've had a couple of requests for more information I will add some more detail. What I would like to do is perform DMA to a Commodore 64's internal memory which is a supported function of the computer. The 6510 CPU can be halted and its bus lines put into a high impedance state so that an external device can access the memory. The external device must respect the video chip accesses which are indicated by a signal line. The 16-bit address bus and 8-bit data bus are available to connect to. The memory is constructed from 4164 DRAM chips of varying speeds the slowest of which are 200ns parts hence the requirement.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining why you would want to.  It certainly makes no sense today as a storage device.  Are you trying to monitor or share data with the other system?   At the rates in question a cheap USB-based logic analyzer could probably capture everything that happens; it's not entirely out of the question that carefully written code could as well.  Do you need to write or is snooping enough?

Comment: It's probably possible, but implementation details will be specific to the device you are interfacing to. What is it?

Comment: I need to write back to RAM. For clarification I want to perform DMA to a vintage microcomputer. The computer's CPU will be halted and tri-stated during this so I only have to share the bus with the video chip.

Comment: @Bruce, Chris See edited question for more details

Comment: The question is going to be if you can activate the I/O's, do something useful, then tristate them and get back out of the way before the next video access - most likely you can.  (A timing diagram of that would help)   If not you could consider a small FPGA, or perhaps replacing the existing DRAM with some dual port SRAM.  You could also consider making a software in-circuit emulator for the CPU, or implementing some communication interface it supports.

Comment: You are probably mixing 5V and 3.3V logic so there is that.  200ns is 5Mhz yes?  That may be a challenge with gpio believe it or not, so you should probably consider a cpld or fpga for the tight timing control and then as needed a microcontroller to drive it if not having something in the fpga if you take that path.

Comment: http://telmomoya.blogspot.co.nz/2016/06/c64-software-cored.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott That link looks promising, thank you. As I understand the article it should be possible to read/write memory by using GPIO pins directly.

Comment: @old_timer Why should the ("low") access time of the RAM be a challenge? That's the *lower* bound for an access, not the upper.

Comment: Looking at [this document](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cbm/c64/vic-ii.txt), it seems that, worst case, the VIC only leaves you one half of a 1MHz clock period, i.e. 500ns, for your bus access. 36 clock cycles @ 72MHz. Not much time to react on the AEC signal.

Comment: OTOH, isn't there a horizontal/vertical blanking period during which the VIC is "idle" and the CPU (or your controller) can access the bus for much longer? - Can't remember after 25 years.